# ARM eabi v7 and Intel x86 Atom is not available in SDK Tools List

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I am new to Android and I was trying to setup development environment on my Ubundu 14.04LTS system. When I try to create virtual device, I am not able to add one since I dont have kernel. When I checked the SDK Tools list, there is no option of ARM EABI to install. So I am not able create the virtual device. What should I do to proceed further?

[image]